# Homomorphic Encryption Verification

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, homomorphic-signatures

How much is it possibile to devide $E(m_1+m_2)$ by $E (m_1)$ to obtain $E (m_2)$ based on the fully Homomorphic-encryption property which says;

$$E (m_1) * E (m_2) = E (m_1 + m_2)$$. And if yes what are the the requirements to apply this property?

Comment: Can you use $E(m^{-1})$?

Comment: What can $E(m−1) mean ?

Comment: Encryption of additive inverse of $m_1$